# import 3d model in SceneKit on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, swift3, scenekit

I have a problem when importing a .obj file from a URL and convert it to a SCNNode

here's the code (swift3):

```
    let url = URL.init(string: "https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/ock9d81kakj91dz1x4ea.obj")
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: url! as URL)
    let object = asset.object(at: 0)
    let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
```

but when i run the project, the console shows that:

```
Could not open OBJ file
```

how to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are exceeding some internal iOS limit with your OBJ file. Please file a report at https://bugreport.apple.com.

This slightly modified version of your code works perfectly in a macOS playground (Xcode 8.0). But in an iOS playground, I see the same "Could not open OBJ file" in the console.

```
import SceneKit
import ModelIO
import SceneKit.ModelIO

if let url = URL.init(string: "https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/ock9d81kakj91dz1x4ea.obj") {
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)
    print(asset)
    let object = asset.object(at: 0)
    print(object)
    let node = SCNNode.init(mdlObject: object)
    print(node)
}
```

I was able to download and open the OBJ file with Xcode. Then within the scene editor, I converted it to SCN format. That gave me a .SCN file that could be embedded in the iOS project and opened with SCNScene (like the famous spinning spaceship). So if you can live with embedding a static file in your iOS app, that's a way to get your model in. But if you need dynamically loaded models, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you, your answer really inspired me. I made a OBJ file by myself, and succeeded

Comment: but if i want to avoid this bug, should i use OpenGL or something else to import OBJ file?

Comment: OpenGL knows nothing about OBJ files. Neither does Metal. You are IMO tickling a bug or limit in ModelIO on iOS. Switching to Metal or OpenGL won't help. Do you have to load the model over the net? If not, simplest fix is to do the OBJ to SCN conversion on your Mac and embed the SCN file instead of using OBJ.

Comment: Unluckily i have to import the model from the net :(  So now I had to go to report the bug.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @humbleCoder were you? 3 years later and still the same error when loading .obj

Answer (score 2):

By they way, if you had the obj file locally, you could just have used:

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ock9d81kakj91dz1x4ea", withExtension: "obj") else { return nil }
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)
    let object = asset.object(at: 0)
    let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should let you load an obj/dae file in swift 4.2/xcode 10.2+:

Create a scenekit model catalog by going to File --> New --> File and selecting "SceneKit Catalog" from the list.

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO
```

Then:

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(
 forResource: "your_obj_filename",
 withExtension: "obj",
 subdirectory: "your_folder.scnassets") 
     else { fatalError("Failed to find model file.") }

let asset = MDLAsset(url:url)
guard let object = asset.object(at: 0) as? MDLMesh 
     else { fatalError("Failed to get mesh from asset.") }

let newNode  = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
```